# Apostrophe shows up as "ÔÇÖ"

Tags: sql-server, character-set

I pulled data out of a database and the apostrophe is showing up as "ÔÇÖ".  What character set is this from?

Comment: It's surprisingly hard to diagnose these type of errors if you run a web server.  You don't know if the error is in the client browser, server side processing scripts, query write code, query read code, query display code, or something else.  Googling this set of characters gave no useful results.

Answer (score 1):

That specific character is from the character set `Chinese_Hong_Kong_Stroke_90`

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to "figure it out" from the output.  The most reliable way is to query the collation off the database.

```
select collation_name from sys.databases;
```